# Shortening optional match query

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a query here that I would like shortening if possible.
The query says that if I post a document, or someone in my department posts a document I would like to return it, if either of those 2 criteria aren't met then nothing is returned and all is good. 
But I don't like the way I have had to do it, so could someone take a quick look and tell me if there is a better way please

```
optional match(document:Document{id:6})-[:SHARED]-()-[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH]-(me:Person{Email:'user@outlook.com'})
optional match(document2:Document{id:6})-[:SHARED]-(me2:Person{Email:'user@outlook.com'})
return document,me,document2,me2
```

As I have to return document, or document2, and me or me2 depending on which match gets a hit it makes things a little messy, is there a way of making it cleaner, so which ever match gets a hit I return document and me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use a zero-length path as a sort of proxy to an optional match. Consider this example dataset:

```
CREATE (doc1:Document {id:1}),
       (doc2:Document {id:2}),
       (doc3:Document {id:3}),

       (you:Person {Email:"shaine@outlook.com"}),
       (colleague:Person {Email:"nicole@outlook.com"}),
       (nonColleague:Person {Email:"julian@outlook.com"}),

       (you)-[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH]->(colleague),
       (you)-[:SHARED]->(doc1),
       (colleague)-[:SHARED]->(doc2),
       (nonColleague)-[:SHARED]->(doc3);
```

In the case of document 1, you shared it so we want it to be returned with you as the sharer. In the case of document 2, your colleague shared it so we want it to be returned with your colleague as the sharer. In the case of document 3, we want no results as neither you nor your colleague shared the document.

We can write a single query that covers all three scenarios by using the zero-length path when matching on the `[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH]` relationship.

Document 1:

```
MATCH (colleague:Person)-[:SHARED]->(doc:Document { id:1 }),
      (:Person { Email:"shaine@outlook.com" })-[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH*0..1]-(colleague)
RETURN colleague.Email, doc.id;

colleague.Email     doc.id
shaine@outlook.com  1
```

Document 2:

```
MATCH (colleague:Person)-[:SHARED]->(doc:Document { id:2 }),
      (:Person { Email:"shaine@outlook.com" })-[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH*0..1]-(colleague)
RETURN colleague.Email, doc.id;

colleague.Email     doc.id
nicole@outlook.com  2
```

Document 3:

```
MATCH (colleague:Person)-[:SHARED]->(doc:Document { id:3 }),
      (:Person { Email:"shaine@outlook.com" })-[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH*0..1]-(colleague)
RETURN colleague.Email, doc.id;

No rows.
```

Note that you are sometimes the "colleague"; in the case that you shared the document you are matched as `colleague` with a length-zero path. You can play with it live here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/yhyrqu

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (me:Person{Email:'user@outlook.com'}), (doc:Document{id:6})
OPTIONAL MATCH (doc)-[r:SHARED]-(me)
WITH me, doc, (CASE WHEN r IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [me] END) AS myself
OPTIONAL MATCH (doc)-[:SHARED]-(p)-[:IN_DEPARTMENT_WITH]-(me)
RETURN doc, COLLECT(p) + myself AS result;
```

This query matches `me` and `doc` just once, and merges two (possibly empty) collections to arrive at the resulting collection of people. The result will contain no rows if the `MATCH` (on the first line) does not find matches.